# Where are Esri LasDatasetBuilder examples?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, arcobjects, lidar, training

Does anyone know of any working examples leveraging the new ESRI ArcGIS 10.1 Lidar classes i.e [LasDataSet](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//0028000001qp000000) or [LasBuilder](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//001q00000mpq000000) class?

I've looked around on http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/ but have not found anything other than the brief descriptions of individual class names and parameters they take in.  However, nothing in respect to working examples and how to tie everything together.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

You might find useful those exercises that resulted from [ArcGIS 10.2 Lidar Workshop](https://www.esri.com/~/media/Files/Pdfs/library/workshops/arcgis102-lidar-workshop.pdf).

The table of contents is the following:

Exercise 1: Create a LAS dataset and explore the lidar data using ArcGIS;
Exercise 2: Create a terrain dataset and analyze the data;
Exercise 3: Create a mosaic dataset and explore the data;
Exercise questions and answers.

Comment: This does not pertain to arc objects.